# Missing Google Analytics Tracking Code

Tags: google-analytics

I installed the Google Analytics tracking code in website.  However, I received this notification: View All Web Site Data is configured for Ecommerce, but no data is flowing.

What seems to be missing in the tracking? TIA!

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing your code. The basic tracking code that you can copy from the property settings will not automatically do e-commerce tracking, you'd need to have extra code at least on your confirmation page where you pass in transaction id and product data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the very basic setup of Google Analytics and haven't configured it to collect Ecommerce data, you should disable Ecommerce in Admin -> View Settings